# Ошибка доступа класса при наследовании

Tags: c#, .net

Есть два класса, при наследовании компилятор выводит ошибку "Inconsistent accessibility base class is less accessible than class."

```
public abstract class WaresTreeDataModel
{
  public abstract void SomeMethod();
}

public sealed class OraWaresTreeDataModel : WaresDataModel
{
   public override void SomeMethod()
   {

   }
}
```

Что тут не так?
Версия .net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: `WaresTreeDataModel` это не `WaresDataModel`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упомянутую Вами ошибку

> Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'B' is less accessible than class 'D'

[можно получить](http://ideone.com/tsGvIn) при компиляции, например, такого кода:

```
internal class B { }

public class D : B { } 

public class Test
{
    public static void Main() { }
}
```

Причина, как мне кажется, должна быть очевидна из текста ошибки. Базовый класс `B` имеет меньший уровень доступа (видимость), чем производный `D`. Чтобы проблему исправить нужно сделать видимость классов согласованной. Например оба сделать `internal`, или оба `public`, или производный сделать менее доступным, чем базовый.